# Shouldn't the Dart analyzer show a warning if a typed function doesn't return a value?

Tags: dart, flutter

For example, take the `builder` parameter for the Redux StoreConnector widget.

```
typedef ViewModelBuilder<ViewModel> = Widget Function(
  BuildContext context,
  ViewModel vm,
);
```

It shows that it returns a Widget. When setting a value to this parameter, the analyzer currently allows you to (incorrectly) define it without a return value.

```
builder: (BuildContext context, Function dispatch) {
         Column(
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          ...
         }
```

This also caused an empty build function, which took a little time to realize the mistake. 
The analyzer catches when other typed functions don't end in a return. A good example is shown in the photo where as soon as you delete the `return`, it shows a warning. Shouldn't this be consistent? I'm asking here before opening a ticket on the Dart Github page.
[image: warning]

Where it shows the return type:
[image: Hover over Builder Function]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the anonymous function is getting typed `Null Function(BuildContext, Function)`. A function that returns `Null` *is* a subtype of a function that returns any other type. (caveat: this is true today, but won't be true with non-nullable types).

As inference and the language is specced today I don't think there is any help the IDE can provide. I filed https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/133 to see if the language could be changed to make this easier.

Comment: The thing is, Intellij shows that it returns a widget when hovering over the property

Comment: Where specifically are you hovering? If it's getting type info from the argument then showing a return type of `Widget` is what we'd expect.

Comment: I'll add another photo to the post

Comment: Yeah, so it's showing you based on the parameter type, not the type of the anonymous function

Comment: My thing is, if it knows it needs to return widget and it doesn't, it should be an error, right? When could this lack of checking be beneficial? The way I see it, maybe incorrectly, is that it says, we need a function that needs to take these parameters and it&#39;ll provide us with this return type so we can process it correctly.